# General Condition for 1st order correction of perturbation theory to be ZERO?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I need some help on the following question regarding perturbation theory of a quantum system:

> Give an example of a perturbation to a system for which the first order correction is zero, and explain a general condition for which this is true.

I understand that for example for a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator with a odd parity perturbation like

$$H' = \gamma \hat x$$

will yield a energy correction of zero.

As the 1st order energy correction is

$$E^{(1)}_n = \langle \psi^{(0)} |H' |\psi^{(0)} \rangle $$.

Am I correct to think that any odd parity perturbation will result in a zero 1st order energy correction ?

Thanks in Advance,

Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the matrix element $\langle \psi^{(0)}|H'|\psi^{(0)}\rangle $ vanishes for odd parity pertubations, IF $|\psi^{(0)} \rangle$ is also an parity eigenstate - as is the case for the harmonic oscillator.

We may understand this (following Sakurai) by noting that if $|\psi^{(0)} \rangle$ is a parity eigenstate, then,
$$\hat \pi |\psi^{(0)} \rangle = (\pm 1) \cdot  |\psi^{(0)} \rangle,$$ while $\hat x$ is uneven under the parity operation, 
$$\hat \pi \hat x \hat \pi^\dagger = - \hat x.$$ 
Finally note that the identity operator may be written as $\hat I = \hat \pi \hat \pi^\dagger$ (since $\hat \pi$ is hermittian and unitary, such that $\hat \pi^\dagger = \hat \pi^{-1}$). Using these three identities we may now show that the matrix element is zero.

We insert the identity operator twice, 
$$\langle \psi^{(0)}|\hat x|\psi^{(0)}\rangle = \langle \psi^{(0)}| (\hat \pi^\dagger \hat \pi) \hat x (\hat \pi^\dagger \hat \pi)|\psi^{(0)}\rangle = (\langle \psi^{(0)}| \hat \pi^\dagger) (\hat \pi \hat x \hat \pi^\dagger) (\hat \pi|\psi^{(0)}\rangle).$$
Then the parity operator acts on the bra, $\langle \psi^{(0)}|$, the position operator, $\hat x$, and the ket, $| \psi^{(0)}\rangle$ according to the two previous identities.
$$= \big(\langle \psi^{(0)}| \cdot (\pm 1)\big)\big((-1) \cdot \hat x \big)\big((\pm 1)\cdot|\psi^{(0)}\rangle\big) = -\langle \psi^{(0)}|\hat x|\psi^{(0)}\rangle.$$
Summing up we reach, $$\langle \psi^{(0)}|\hat x|\psi^{(0)}\rangle = -\langle \psi^{(0)}|\hat x|\psi^{(0)}\rangle.$$
Thus the matrix element is some number which is equal to *minus* itself (that is, some number $k$ which fulfills $k=-k$). Only one number has this property - namely zero. $$\langle \psi^{(0)}|\hat x|\psi^{(0)}\rangle=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and confirmation of my line of thought!